# Audio not playing after calling .Play()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an AudioManager for my Game. When I try to play a clip on a NPC it doesn't get played. The script itself works because the background music is playing properly.

The code of the relevant parts:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;

public class AudioManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private AudioSource audioSource;
    private AudioSource backgroundPlayer;

    private Dictionary<string, Sound> audioClips;
    public List<Sound> background;

    void Start()
    {
        Sound current = background[background.Count-1];

        backgroundPlayer.clip = current.clip;
        backgroundPlayer.volume = current.volume;
        backgroundPlayer.pitch = current.pitch;
        backgroundPlayer.Play();     //works absolutely fine
    }

public void SetCurrentSource(AudioSource a)
    {
        audioSource = a;
    }

    public void Play(string name, string NPCSpeaker)
    {
        string actualName = name + "_" + NPCSpeaker;
        if (audioClips.ContainsKey(actualName))
        {
            audioSource.clip = audioClips[actualName].clip;
            audioSource.volume = audioClips[actualName].volume;
            audioSource.pitch = audioClips[actualName].pitch;
            Debug.Log("Start Audio  " + audioSource.clip);
            audioSource.Play();
            Debug.Log(audioSource.isPlaying);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("AudioClip with name "+ actualName + " is not found." );
        }
    }
```

And the Sound Class:

```
public class Sound
{
    public string name;

    public AudioClip clip;

    [Range(0f, 1f)]
    public float volume;
    [Range(.1f, 3f)]
    public float pitch;
}
```

Before I call `Play()`, I always call `setCurrentSource()` because the `audioSource` is the current NPC in the conversation.
Clip, volume and pitch are set correctly and are not null.
I found out, when I debug it, set a breakpoint in `Play()` somewhere and go to the point of calling `audioSource.Play()`, then open the inspector to view the object informations in VS Code, it will play the audio. If i just wait at `audioSource.Play()` it doesn't.
The Debug statement `Debug.Log(audioSource.isPlaying)` returns false.

As said I can hear the music, so Editor isn't muted.
Gameobject with the AudioSource Component is activated.

Edit: Creating the AudioClips:

```
    void Awake()
    {
        backgroundPlayer = gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        createAudioClips();

        audioClips = new Dictionary<string, Sound>();
        foreach (Sound s in sounds)
        {
            audioClips.Add(s.name, s);
        }
    }
```

```
private void createAudioClips()
    {
        string rel = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/Audio/";
        string[] paths = new string[] { rel + "Brian", rel + "Matthew", rel + "Russell", rel + "Leader", rel + "Scientist" };

        foreach (string p in paths)
        {
            foreach (string fileName in Directory.GetFiles(p))
            {
                if (Path.GetExtension(fileName) == ".mp3")
                {
                    if (p == rel + "Scientist")
                    {
                        CreateNewSound(fileName, true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        CreateNewSound(fileName, false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void CreateNewSound(string filename, bool isScientist)
    {
        WWW request = new WWW(filename);

        string[] subs = filename.Split('\\');

        Sound newSound = new Sound();
        newSound.name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename);
        newSound.clip = request.GetAudioClip();
        if (isScientist)
        {
            newSound.volume = 1f;
        }
        else
        {
            newSound.volume = 0.5f;
        }
        
        newSound.pitch = 1f;
        sounds.Add(newSound);
    }
```

The Soundfiles are .mp3 and are in the StreamingAssets Folder.

Comment: Have you tried [PlayOneShot](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.PlayOneShot.html) instead of `Play`?

Comment: You reference a variable background in your start. And none is defined so I’m guessing this code is not the code running

Comment: @Chuck I tried but it doesn't help.

Comment: @BugFinder The Class is way longer so I left out parts of it. Didn't saw I forgot this line. (I edited it in now)

Comment: @SörenPrecht - how are you populating the `audioClips` Dictionary?

Comment: @Chuck I added a Edit to my Question with the infos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED]
The problem is in the Loading part. With WWW the sounds didn't got created right.
I changed createAudioClips() and createNewSound() to

```
private void createAudioClips()
    {
        string rel = "Audio";
        string[] paths = new string[] { "Brian", "Matthew", "Russell", "Leader", "Scientist" };

        foreach (string p in paths)
        {
            string abs = Path.Combine(rel, p);
            var files = Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "Resources", abs));
            foreach (string fileName in files)
            {
                if (Path.GetExtension(fileName) == ".mp3")
                {
                    if (p == rel + "Scientist")
                    {
                        createNewSound(fileName, abs, true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        createNewSound(fileName, abs, false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void createNewSound(string filename, string abs, bool isScientist)
    {
        Sound newSound = new Sound();
        newSound.name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename);
        string file = Path.Combine(abs, newSound.name);
        newSound.clip = Resources.Load(file) as AudioClip;
        if (isScientist)
        {
            newSound.volume = 1f;
        }
        else
        {
            newSound.volume = 0.5f;
        }
        newSound.pitch = 1f;
        sounds.Add(newSound);
    }
```

It work fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You just edited to show how you're loading the audio clips and I don't know if you're actually getting anything out of this. It looks like you've got two different mechanisms going at the same time. On the one hand you're calling:

```
foreach (string fileName in Directory.GetFiles(p))
```

This looks like you're trying to get to local files because [you cannot use the `Directory` class to list files of a Web directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17041674/5171120). On the other hand, when you actually try to get the clip, you're calling:

```
WWW request = new WWW(filename);
newSound.clip = request.GetAudioClip();
```

Which then looks like you're trying to do something web-related. But your `filename` is the output of `Directory.GetFiles()` which, again, is not for web things.

Since you're saying your debug statements are working when you try to play the clip:

> The Debug statement Debug.Log(audioSource.isPlaying) returns false.

I'm going to assume that you're actually building your Dictionary, which means all the rest of the clip-loading code is probably firing. This makes me think that your audio clips are not actually getting loaded and you're probably trying to play a `null` clip. This would be why you're not hearing anything.

As a troubleshooting step, try the following for your `CreateNewSound` method:

```
private void CreateNewSound(string filename, bool isScientist)
{
    WWW request = new WWW(filename);

    string[] subs = filename.Split('\\');

    Sound newSound = new Sound();
    newSound.name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename);
    newSound.clip = request.GetAudioClip();
    // New Debug statement:
    if(newSound.clip == null)
    {
        Debug.LogErrorFormat("Failed to load a clip for {0}", filename);
    }
    // End new Debug statement
    if (isScientist)
    {
        newSound.volume = 1f;
    }
    else
    {
        newSound.volume = 0.5f;
    }
    
    newSound.pitch = 1f;
    sounds.Add(newSound);
}
```

See if this starts giving you Debug Errors that it's not loading the clip.

Comment: The files are local as you guessed. They are in the SreamingAssets Folder of Unity.
For the CreateNewSound() Method I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9gAHZGArDgU
I tried your suggestion. Result:
All Sounds are loaded and I don't get any Errors

Comment: I debugged further and found the following:
breakpoint in VS Code at `audioSource.clip = audioClips[actualName].clip;`
open inspector of right clip -> channel, frequency, length all 0.
close inspector and open again -> Vaules are there and audio will get played.
Same when i do it for the first clip after assigning it.
So the infos of the clip are not loaded correctly.