# How to Copy all files from Http Directory?

Tags: c#, http, iis, copy

i have IIS deployed web site on which i have virtual folder containing folders and files.
i am using following code to copy the files from Http site. but i copy only one file at a time. instead of coping files one by one i want to **copy all directory**.

```
 private static void DirectoryCopy(string sourceDirName, string destDirName, bool copySubDirs)
    {
        // Get the subdirectories for the specified directory.
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirName);
        DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();

        if (!dir.Exists)
        {
            throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(
                "Source directory does not exist or could not be found: "
                + sourceDirName);
        }

        // If the destination directory doesn't exist, create it. 
        if (!Directory.Exists(destDirName))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirName);
        }

        // Get the files in the directory and copy them to the new location.
        FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, file.Name);
            file.CopyTo(temppath, false);
        }

        // If copying subdirectories, copy them and their contents to new location. 
        if (copySubDirs)
        {
            foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in dirs)
            {
                string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, subdir.Name);
                DirectoryCopy(subdir.FullName, temppath, copySubDirs);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: May be help you                 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124492/c-sharp-httpwebrequest-command-to-get-directory-listing

Comment: Please see link :                                 http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34415/Downloading-Multiple-Files-over-HTTP-Connection

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try to make the whole operation asynchronous, but I'm not sure if the result will be satisfactory for you. I have never heard of a function that could copy everything at once. In every OS there is a queue of files waiting to be written ;)

If the operation takes too much time, simply use ajax and notify the user of the current progress, so the website doesn't just freez on him without any notification.

Comment: files in that directory always changing. how can i get those file names?? that's why i want to copy all folder

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use FTP directory to download all file in specific directory.

For being able to download all files from a FTP directory to a local folder, you will have to list all files in the remote directory and then download them one by one. You can use the following code to do the same:

```
    string[] files = GetFileList();
    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        Download(file);
    }

    public string[] GetFileList()
    {
        string[] downloadFiles;
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        WebResponse response = null;
        StreamReader reader = null;
        try
        {
            FtpWebRequest reqFTP;
            reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "/"));
            reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
            reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUserID, ftpPassword);
            reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
            reqFTP.Proxy = null;
            reqFTP.KeepAlive = false;
            reqFTP.UsePassive = false;
            response = reqFTP.GetResponse();
            reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string line = reader.ReadLine();
            while (line != null)
            {
                result.Append(line);
                result.Append("\n");
                line = reader.ReadLine();
            }
            // to remove the trailing '\n'
            result.Remove(result.ToString().LastIndexOf('\n'), 1);
            return result.ToString().Split('\n');
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (reader != null)
            {
                reader.Close();
            }
            if (response != null)
            {
                response.Close();
            }                
            downloadFiles = null;
            return downloadFiles;
        }
    }

    private void Download(string file)
    {                       
        try
        {                
            string uri = "ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "/" + remoteDir + "/" + file;
            Uri serverUri = new Uri(uri);
            if (serverUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeFtp)
            {
                return;
            }       
            FtpWebRequest reqFTP;                
            reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "/" + remoteDir + "/" + file));                                
            reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUserID, ftpPassword);                
            reqFTP.KeepAlive = false;                
            reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;                                
            reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
            reqFTP.Proxy = null;                 
            reqFTP.UsePassive = false;
            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)reqFTP.GetResponse();
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            FileStream writeStream = new FileStream(localDestnDir + "\" + file, FileMode.Create);                
            int Length = 2048;
            Byte[] buffer = new Byte[Length];
            int bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);               
            while (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
            }                
            writeStream.Close();
            response.Close(); 
        }
        catch (WebException wEx)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(wEx.Message, "Download Error");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Download Error");
        }
    }
```

Comment: i dont have the file list saved somewhere. these files are generated by my program, and its names and count always changing

Answer (score 0):

Copying a directory does not exist. You create a new destination directory and copy all files in the source directory. If the source directory contains directories, repeat the process for each directory in there, ad infinitum.

Your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19175736/how-to-copy-all-files-from-http-directory#comment28369640_19175868) here indicates you're actually trying to solve another problem. What is that problem?

If your actual problem is that files *disappear* between `dir.GetFiles()` and `file.CopyTo()`, apply the appropriate `try..catch` clauses to catch errors of files not existing anymore.

If your actual problem is that files are *added* between `dir.GetFiles()` and `file.CopyTo()`, keep a list of the names of files that you *did* copy, call `dir.GetFiles()` again after copying all and intersect the results to see if new files were added.