# Loading multiple XDocuments, and working with its documents

Tags: c#, xml

I wrote several lines of code but still can't get over this:

I need to load many xml docs from web library. I don't know how many documents there are so I wonder which loop should I use while loading:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("http://" + i);
```

where -i is identifiers number. 
I tried loading until i get document without meaningful content (thought it is the end, the rest are empty), but problem is that there is several Xdocs that are empty in the middle of library.

XML with content looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OP xmlns="" xmlns:xsi="" xsi:schemaLocation="">
<request verb="GR" identifier="53" metadataPrefix="p"></request>
<GR>
<header>
<identifier>53,number of doc...used for counting</identifier>
</header>
<metadata>
<P xmlns="" xsi:schemaLocation="">
<TITLE>title</TITLE>
<CERTIFICATE NAME="different names">
</CERTIFICATE>
<YEAR>
<DATE>2012-10-18T00:00:00Z</DATE>
</YEAR>
<MINIATURE>
<COPY>
<CNAME>Copy name<CNAME>
<FORMAT>obj/max/dxf/3ds/...</FORMAT>
</COPY>
</MINIATURE>
</metadata>
</GR>
</OP>
```

XML without content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OP xmlns="" xmlns:xsi="" xsi:schemaLocation="">
<request verb="GR" identifier="53" metadataPrefix="p"></request>
```

Furthermore, I need to do some counting like:

```
Tot.no. of doc, 
No. of docs per certificate <CERTIFICATE>
No. of docs for each year <YEAR><DATE>
No of docs for each format <MINIATURE><COPY><FORMAT>
```

and my output should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Statistic>
<DocSum>21220</DocSum>
<Certificates>
<Certificate id=”certificateName”>17098</Certificate>
…
<Certificates>
<Years>
<Year year=”2014”>23</Year>
…
</Years>
<Miniature>
<Format post=”obj”>11723</Format>
…
</Miniature>
</Statistic>
```

If you could give me some help, hints or tips how to deal with it.

Comment: If you don't know how many documents there are and how to get that information, how on earth do you expect us to know that?

Comment: how could I know. If i write http://...identifier=10000, the document is there...If identifier=200000 document empty, if identifier=30000 document with content. I tried to find last document randomly typing in browser and its about 30000...but how can I be sure that on 100000 doc is empty.

Comment: @Mrvoje - This question is impossible to answer until you provide some more detail about your data source.  From the code you posted, one can infer that your are loading the documents over the web.  Are these files in a directory on your web server?  Are they generated by a database?  What kind of database?  Are you calling some web service that serves XML documents?

Comment: no, I'm just loading em from http://3d.probado.igd.fraunhofer.de/Probado3DOAI/?verb=GetRecord&metadataPrefix=p3dm&identifier=1     currently: server error, but there is document similar to one above...I changed it a little.

Answer (score 0):

The posted answer by [smink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6508/smink) to the following thread should get you on the right path.

[C# HttpWebRequest command to get directory listing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124492/c-sharp-httpwebrequest-command-to-get-directory-listing)

One of the easiest ways to get a list of the files of a web directory without knowing exactly how many there are or their filenames is by parsing the html of the directory and pulling out the  tags.

You can then iterate through these tags and filter them out for the files by extensions that you need. I can provide a more in-depth example if necessary.

Comment: seams it's necessary. Please