# Get file name from url using c# or download file from url without specifying filename

Tags: c#, ssis

I'm using script component. I want to download csv file which is part of url - http://test/todaydate04232019.csv

This part:04232019 of file name is date so it will change daily.

I have used code

```
client.downloadfile(url,localpath)
```

It is working fine but when i exclude filename in url, it's not working.

Comment: please add your code and correctly format it to get help

Comment: What is the name you want to extract? Is it `04232019.csv`? If it is you can try regular expression: `string name = Regex.Match(url.ToString(), "[0-9]{8}\.csv").Value;`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [UriBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uribuilder?view=netframework-4.8) class to decompose a `Uri` into its various parts. The [Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uribuilder.path?view=netframework-4.8#System_UriBuilder_Path) property should give you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you build the path with the date of the day like this ?

```
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        String dateString = now.Month.ToString("00") + now.Day.ToString("00") + now.Year.ToString("0000");
        String url = "http://test/todaydate" + dateString + ".csv";

        ...

        client.downloadfile(url, localpath);
```

Comment: I already tried this. But business preferred downloading file from url

Comment: Isn't 
"String url = "http://test/todaydate" + dateString + ".csv";"
the URL the business is looking for ?

Comment: Yes that is but sometimes, API doesn't show today's date. It means file might not have uploaded. In such case, package will fail

Comment: So if you don't know the filename, I suggest this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/124522/11202463

Comment: Thanks. How to check If file available or not on URL? Let's say, for some reason, today file not uploaded. How to check that?

Comment: Can client.downloadfile(url,localpath) return false if not succeded ?