# Get queries from github and execute them in order

Tags: sql-server, github, ssis, azure-data-factory

I have in my github repo several folders with queries.

folder Common
folder

is also a variable in my project.

I would like to use ADFv2 IS to 
1. get all the queries  in the folder common and execute these in alphanumeric order
2. get all the queries  in the folder  and execute these in alphanumeric order

Any idea how this can be done? Can ADFv2 IS get data from github and f.e. store the contents in a table?

Answer (score 0):

Use a script task

```
string URL = [url of the file you want];
System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
wc.DownloadFile(URL,@"c:\SQL.sql");
```

Comment: That would allow me to execute a known query. More interesting would be how to enumerate all the files with extension .sql and then use your code to execute them.
The whole goal is not to know waht queries are in the folder, I want to execute them all. (I realise the security risk, I need it for a proof of concept)

Comment: This link can help you get the files to loop through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124492/c-sharp-httpwebrequest-command-to-get-directory-listing